# Unhandled exception error with OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to run a program that uses the OpenCV library. The program is successfully compiled but when I try to run it I get the following error:

Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFA62F6A74A (igdrcl64.dll) in ConvNetUtil.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000994.

I get this error both in debug and release mode.

My code is really simple:

```
Mat nImage;
cv::resize(img, nImage, _sizes[i]);
vector<PyRect> v;
```

I am trying to resize a mat image that is read correctly from disk in previous lines.

I am using OpenCV version 3. Thank you!

Comment: Did you check img is read successfully (img.empy() is false)? _sizes[i] is valid (non-zero)? what is your PyRect?

Comment: img is read successfully as the rows and cols are correct and img.empty() is false. _sizes[i] is a vector of size(w,h) in this case _size[0] has a w=450 and h=431. The program crashes in the resize line. The code used to work but now i recompiled it is not. I am not mixing dll files for debug and release and i have opencv_world310.lib file for release and opencv_world310d.lib for debug. Any help will be very  much appreciated

Comment: igdrcl64.dll is belonged to Intel HD Graphic Driver. I don't know ConvNetUtil exactly but could you reinstall the graphic driver and try again?

Comment: ConvNetUtil is a program I made that uses the Caffe Deep Learning framework. I have successfully compiled caffe on windows and linked the produced caffe.lib and caffed.lib on debug and release mode. I am using a nvidia gpu so I dont know why a dll from intel HD is used. I am also on visual studio 13, I have cuda version 7.0 installed and OpenCV version 3.1.

Comment: You can separate these line into another simple application and see it works or not.

Answer (score 5):

You can resolve this error by doing these steps;

```
Uninstall Intel Graphics Driver.
Restart
Remove the following files:

On 64-bit version of Windows OS:
C:\Windows\System32\igdbcl64.dll
C:\Windows\System32\igdfcl64.dll
C:\Windows\System32\igdrcl64.dll
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\igdbcl32.dll
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\igdfcl32.dll
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\igdrcl32.dll
On 32-bit version of Windows OS:
C:\Windows\System32\igdbcl32.dll
C:\Windows\System32\igdfcl32.dll
C:\Windows\System32\igdrcl32.dll
```

Comment: Man, you right here just brought a smile on my face after hours of frustration, cursing and annoyance! Love you

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem today. I solved it by uninstalling Intel graphics driver, and rebuild the OpenCV library with `WITH_OPENGL` flag unchecked.

[My CMake setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjXn0.png)