# OpenCvSharp Access Violation

Tags: c#, opencv, access-violation

I am using OpenCvSharp4 4.1.0.20190416 and function for deep neural networks.

```
        ...
        mDnn.SetInput(blob, "data");
        // get output layer name
        var outNames = mDnn.GetUnconnectedOutLayersNames();
        // create mats for output layer
        Mat[] outs = outNames.Select(_ => new Mat()).ToArray();
        // Run dnn
        mDnn.Forward(outs, outNames);
        ...
```

When during debugging step over the mDnn.Forward row, after while application crashed with access violation. But calling mDnn.Forward returns results without any problem. I don't have any idea, where could be problem.

```
Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have found solution. It seems that everything can be solved by enabling 
"Enable native code debugging" property in project properties at debug tab.

**UPDATE**

After enabling this property, application crash on different error.
Finally the problem was in Intel Graphic driver version:24
I have to uninstall the driver and everything is ok.
[Uninstallation process](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41073881/1756072)